# Merging plink files with divergent allele codings

Tags: plink

I have a number of plink files from different arrays (mixed Illumina and Affymetrix) that need to be merged. However, these use different allele codings, so trying to merge without fixing this causes an error (3+ alleles). One can fix this by using (on each file) `--recode 12` to a PED file, and then converting back to BED (`--make-bed`) and then merging (`--merge-list`). Doing this, I was able to merge the files without explicit errors. However, this method is suboptimal, I think, because a minor allele in dataset 1 might not be the same one as in dataset 2, since this depends on the people in the dataset.

For instance, rs746969. Illumina 1MDuo:

```
10  rs746969    1.00698e+06 100008620   1   2
```

Affymetrix 6.0:

```
10  rs746969    0   100008620   A   G
```

Alternatively, I could keep the `12-encoded` merged data, and attempt to convert back to ACGT. Which is the best approach?

Comment: Yes I would advise against doing the first option, since like you say, you don't know the minor allele is going to be the same between the different datasets. When merging two different datasets, it is very important that you make sure there aren't any strand flips and that the alleles line up. I would reccomend making sure that both datsets are in the ACGT format and then using something like [genotype harmonizer](https://github.com/molgenis/systemsgenetics/wiki/Genotype-Harmonizer) to check for strand flips.